# Remapping Alt-Tab behaviour on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard

How can I remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour in Xubuntu? I'd like to map this to a different combination as I'd like to keep <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> reserved to virtual machines that I run. I am aware that keyboard focus for VirtualBox can be switched by tapping <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but I would prefer a distinct combination for each.

It is not one of the mappings in `Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts`, and I can't add a new mapping as I don't know what command it uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my distribution of Xubuntu, Alt+Tab cycles through open windows. To change this shortcut, go to `Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard`, find the 'Cycle windows' action, and hit the edit button.

[image: Cycle Windows Shortcut]